# How To enable the Google Meet API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-meet

I am trying to use the Google Meet API to join the meeting and capture the audio stream.

I didn't find any API from Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [Google Community Help](https://support.google.com/meet/thread/212659042/how-to-enable-the-google-meet-api?hl=en) Doc,

> To enable the Google Meet API and use its features, follow these
> steps: Access the Google Cloud Console. Create a new project or select
> an existing one. In the left sidebar, select "APIs and Services" and
> then "Library". In the search bar, type "Google Meet" and select the
> Google Meet API. Click the "Enable" button to enable the API in your
> project. In the left sidebar, select "Credentials" and then "Create
> Credentials". Select "API Key" and then select "Create". Copy the
> generated API key and use it in your requests. With the API enabled
> and the credentials created, you can use the Google Meet API documents
> to integrate the desired functionality into your application.

- In Google Meet there is an option called record, click on the recording button, if it asks permission give the necessary permissions then this will record the audio and screen aswell.
- You can also use a screen recording tool or audio recording tool  to capture the audio stream, this needs to get a proper consent from Google.
- Refer to this [Google support doc](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10090454) for tracking attendance, live
  streaming report.

Comment: I cannot see google meet when I search for it.  Google meet is also missing in the workspace APIs

Comment: There are contradictory answers in the thread where the quoted answer was posted. The author of the quote answer has a silver badge, while the other answer was posted by someone with a Diamond badge. It's very likely that the quoted answer was generated by AI as there is no Google Meet API.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 13, 2023, there is no Google Meet API. According to https://developers.google.com/meet, there is a [Meet Live Sharing SDK](https://developers.google.com/meet/live-sharing/guides/overview)

> The Google Meet Live Sharing SDK lets you improve your apps to include co-watching, co-doing, and other Meet experiences for your users.

> **Next steps**
> Preview: The Google Meet Live Sharing SDK is in preview. To use the SDK, developers can apply for access through our Early Access Program. After your EAP application is approved, and you've been onboarded by the Meet team, you can download the latest SDK release from Google's Maven repository.